# How to add chapters to mp4 files on ipad/ios

Tags: ios, metadata, mp4

I want to make an app that allow users to add chapters to videos on ipad. I have been able to save videos as mp4 files, but don't know how to add the appropriate metadata to add chapters. How can I do it?